# Java Mouse Events location are relative to whether the window is bordered

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mouse

I have created a `JFrame` and attached a `MouseListener` to it.  The problem that I am having is that `MouseEvents` methods `getXOnScreen()` and `getYOnScreen()` return different results when the `JFrame` is bordered compared to when it isn't.
I am looking to disable this behavior so the methods only return the value relative to the `Canvas` object that implements `MouseListener`.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  It is very rare that you would want to attach a `MouseListener` directly to frame

Comment: will you provide the example as what you exactly expecting from us?